# How to make numerical integration of this expression more stable?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

We have to solve the following expression,

$$
 \int_{0}^{+\infty} 
 w^{\alpha - 1 - p^2 - p \frac{n - p - 1}{2}} 
 e^{ - \alpha w }
 \left(1+\frac{tr(\Sigma^{-1} A)}{w \nu}\right)^{-\frac{\nu + pn}{2}} dw,
$$

where $\Sigma$ and $A$ are symmetric pd matrices of dimension $p$ by $p$ and $\alpha$, $\nu$ and $n$ are positive reals.

Unfortunately numerical integration seems very unstable. I unsucessfully let a computer algebra system try to solve the integral theoretically. We don't have a mathematician on our team so I'm asking here, if maybe you see a way to manipulate the integral, so that numerical integration becomes a more stable? Or if you have any other advice?

Example parameter values for which numerical integration returns an obviously wrong value (and also returns a warning) are:
$\alpha = 1$, $p = 3$, $n = 4$, $tr(\Sigma^{-1} A) = 79$, $\nu = 3$. Then the function under the integral looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Gauss–Laguerre quadrature https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Laguerre_quadrature  also look at Generalized Gauss–Laguerre quadrature to deal with $\frac1{w}$ singularity

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity

Comment: Is $tr(\Sigma^{-1}A)$ just a constant? Can you please share parameter values for which the integration is unstable?

Comment: @arthur Thanks for the tip. I am now looking into https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26737-legendre-laguerre-and-hermite-gauss-quadrature and will reply the results.

Comment: @uranix Yes, $tr(\Sigma^{-1} A)$ is just a constant, since it is the trace of the matrix product inside. However, it is connected to the parameter $p$, as $p$ is the dimension of both matrices. Trouble parameter values have been added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $I$ denote the integral in question. Writing

$$ \beta = \alpha - p^2 - \frac{p(n - p - 1)}{2}, \qquad
\gamma = \frac{\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma^{-1} A)}{\nu}, \qquad
\delta = \frac{\nu + pn}{2}, $$

the integral simplifies to

$$ I = \int_{0}^{+\infty} w^{\beta-1} e^{-\alpha w} \left(1+\frac{\gamma}{w}\right)^{-\delta} \, \mathrm{d}w
\stackrel{(w=\gamma v)}= \gamma^{\beta} \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-\alpha\gamma v} v^{\beta+\delta-1}(1+v)^{-\delta} \, \mathrm{d}v. $$

Assuming that $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ are all real numbers, this integral converges if and only if either

$$ \begin{cases}
\alpha \gamma > 0, \ \beta+\delta>0, &\text{or} \\
\alpha \gamma = 0, \ \beta+\delta>0, \ \beta < 0.
\end{cases} $$

In such case, it reduces to a well-studied special function called the [Tricomi's confluent hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function) (a.k.a. [confluent hypergeometric function of the second kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheSecondKind.html)) denoted by $U(a, b, z)$. Using this function, we may write

$$ I = \gamma^{\beta}\Gamma(\beta+\delta) U(\beta+\delta, \beta+1, \alpha\gamma). $$

Since there is already an extensive literature on this function (and even some mathematics software are wielded with it), one might possibly benefit from this.

Comment: Wow! This is amazing! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

With the numbers you have given wolfram states that the integral does not converge:

```
integrate x^(-9) exp(-x) (1 + 79/(3*x))^(-15/2) dx , x = 0 to infinity
```

[Wolfram with above command](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20x%5E%28-9%29%20exp%28-x%29%20%281%20%2B%2079%2F%283*x%29%29%5E%28-15%2F2%29%20dx%20%2C%20x%20%3D%200%20to%20infinity) (press enter if non convergence message does not appear)

[image]

**The $\frac1{x^9}$ is a non removable singularity.**

You may have to question the derivation and application of the equation.